# QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER function doesn't trigger (“no data exchange”)

Tags: php, quickbooks, qbxml

I'm trying to synchronize my OpenCart with QB Desktop.
But it doesn't work. QB Web Connector says "no data exchange".

Here is my code:

```
// Map QuickBooks actions to handler functions
$map = array(
    QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER => array( '_quickbooks_customer_add_request', '_quickbooks_customer_add_response' ),
);

$errmap = array(
    '*' => '_quickbooks_error_catchall',
);

$hooks = array();

$log_level = QUICKBOOKS_LOG_DEVELOP;

$soapserver = QUICKBOOKS_SOAPSERVER_BUILTIN
$soap_options = array();

$handler_options = array(
    'deny_concurrent_logins' => false,
    'deny_reallyfast_logins' => false,
);      // See the comments in the QuickBooks/Server/Handlers.php file

$driver_options = array(        // See the comments in the QuickBooks/Driver/<YOUR DRIVER HERE>.php file ( i.e. 'Mysql.php', etc. )
    'max_log_history' => 32000, // Limit the number of quickbooks_log entries  to 1024
    'max_queue_history' => 1024,    // Limit the number of *successfully processed* quickbooks_queue entries to 64
);

$callback_options = array();

// Set up our queue singleton
QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue_Singleton::initialize($dsn);

$Server = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server($dsn, $map, $errmap, $hooks, $log_level, $soapserver, QUICKBOOKS_WSDL, $soap_options, $handler_options, $driver_options, $callback_options);
$response = $Server->handle(true, true);

function _quickbooks_customer_add_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID,  $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
{
// Grab the data from our MySQL database
$arr = array(
    'name' => 'opencart' . date('ymdhis'),
    'fname' => 'opencart'. date('ymdhis'),
    'lname' => 'opencart'. date('ymdhis'),
);

$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
    <QBXML>
        <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
            <CustomerAddRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                <CustomerAdd>
                    <Name>' . $arr['name'] . '</Name>
                    <CompanyName>' . $arr['name'] . '</CompanyName>
                    <FirstName>' . $arr['fname'] . '</FirstName>
                    <LastName>' . $arr['lname'] . '</LastName>
                </CustomerAdd>
            </CustomerAddRq>
        </QBXMLMsgsRq>
    </QBXML>';

return $xml;
}
```

Here is my test handle.php code which queue a new customer:

```
if (isset($_GET['customer_id']))
{
    $id = intval($_GET['customer_id']);

    // Queue up the customer add

    $Queue = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue($dsn);
    $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER, $id);

    die('Great, queued up a customer!');
}
```

It adds a new record to the database:

```
quickbooks_queue_id = 609
quickbooks_ticket_id = null
qb_username = someuser
qb_action = CustomerAdd
ident = 123456
extra = empty
qbxml = empty
priority = 0
qb_status = q
enqueue_datetime = 2016-02-02 20:58:50
dequeue_datetime = null
```

Web Connector log:

```
20160204.06:45:32 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : updateWS() for application = 'QuickBooks Bridge for OpenCart' has STARTED
20160204.06:45:32 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.getUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock = FALSE
20160204.06:45:32 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to True
20160204.06:45:32 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session locked *********************
20160204.06:45:32 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : Initiated connection to the following application.
20160204.06:45:32 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppName: QuickBooks Bridge for OpenCart
20160204.06:45:32 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppUniqueName (if available): QuickBooks Bridge for OpenCart
20160204.06:45:32 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppURL: https://example.com/qbwc.php
20160204.06:45:32 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : *** Calling serverVersion().
20160204.06:45:32 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : Received from serverVersion() following parameter:<serverVersionRet="PHP QuickBooks SOAP Server v3.0 at /wce/qbwc.php">
20160204.06:45:32 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : *** Calling clientVersion() with following parameter:<productVersion="2.2.0.34">
20160204.06:45:33 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : Received from clientVersion() following parameter:<clientVersionRet="">
20160204.06:45:33 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : This application agrees with the current version of QBWebConnector. Allowing update operation.
20160204.06:45:33 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : Authenticating to application 'QuickBooks Bridge for OpenCart', username = 'someuser'
20160204.06:45:33 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : *** Calling authenticate() with following parameters:<userName="someuser"><password=<MaskedForSecurity>
20160204.06:45:33 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.updateWS() : Received from authenticate() following parameters:<authRet[0]="1c44d47f-1542-1854-3d22-0d9569718c76"><authRet[1]="13355f1b-4b26-4a7b-b182-15c6dd1246f9"><authRet[2]="1"><authRet[3]="">
20160204.06:45:33 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setCurrentWebServiceName() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\CurrentWebServiceName has been set to QuickBooks Bridge for OpenCart
20160204.06:45:33 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setCurrentWebServiceSessionTicket() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\CurrentWebServiceSessionTicket has been set to 1c44d47f-1542-1854-3d22-0d9569718c76
20160204.06:45:33 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.CheckCFNResponse() : User authenticated.
20160204.06:45:33 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.HandleDelayRequest() : Update has been postponed at 2/3/2016 10:45:33 PM by 'QuickBooks Bridge for OpenCart' for next 60 seconds
20160204.06:45:33 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : Done.
20160204.06:45:33 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to False
20160204.06:45:33 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session unlocked *********************
20160204.06:45:33 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : No data to exchange for the application:  QuickBooks Bridge for OpenCart
```

I've added a `die()` to the `_quickbooks_customer_add_request` but it ignores this function.

Does any know how to solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you get "No data exchange required." it means there's nothing in the queue for the Web Connector to process, or you have something badly misconfigured.

Since you *do* have records in the `quickbooks_queue` table, my first guess would be that the Web Connector is connecting as a *different user* than what's in the queue table.

Can you confirm that the .QWC file you used uses this username?

```
someuser
```

Short of that, you have something misconfigured. Based on your logs, it looks like you have something misconfigured. Specifically:

`qb_company_file: 13355f1b-4b26-4a7b-b182-15c6dd1246f9;`

This should be a *file path* pointing to your QuickBooks company file (hit F2 in QuickBooks to see it) or it should be empty. That value is definitely not a valid Windows file path.

Also, this:

`qwbc_min_run_every_n_seconds: 60`

Remove this. You should not have this set either unless you have a very good, very specific reason for doing so. It is incompatible with several versions of the Web Connector.

Did you follow the quick-start guide? You would not run into these issues if you had...

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

Comment: Yes, I confirm that. I've updated my question with WC log.

Comment: Are you positive you haven't changed any of the code inside the QuickBooks/ lib folder? The Web Connector is showing that your SOAP server is returning an invalid response format. This is very, very wrong:

Comment: <authRet[0]="1c44d47f-1542-1854-3d22-0d9569718c76"><authRet[1]="13355f1b-4b26-4a7b-b182-15c6dd1246f9"><authRet[2]="1"><authRet[3]="">

Comment: What does the record in your quickbooks_user SQL table look like?

Comment: Yes I'm using composer so that vendor/consolibyte/quickbooks folder is untouched. quickbooks_user table looks like: qb_username: someuser; qb_password: plaintextpassword; qb_company_file: 13355f1b-4b26-4a7b-b182-15c6dd1246f9; qwbc_wait_before_next_update: 0; qwbc_min_run_every_n_seconds: 60; status: e; write_datetame and touch_datetime contain a valid datetime.

Comment: OK, I will update my answer -- that is very obviously a very incorrect configuration. I have no idea where you go that from.

Comment: @SergiiMatrunchyk Updated my answer based on the new details you provided.

Comment: You're my saviour. I had a misunderstanding of Company File and FileID - I thought it is the same. Thank you so much!